# Cannot build wheels for nmslib

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for nmslib
Failed to build nmslib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for nmslib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project
```

I tried to install nmslib/spacy/scispacy from git, but error persists.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your Python version and OS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.